# How do I make an API call like this in SpringMVC?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, api, spring-mvc

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=KEY&location=" + address,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                },
                success: function (response, status) {
                    alert("OK");//alerts OK, but NONE of the followinng
                    lati = response.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lat;
                    lng = response.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lng;
                    console.log(lati, lng);
                },
                error: function (data, status) {
                    console.log(data.errors);

                }});
        }
```

I need to make a web call like this but in Spring MVC to get the lat and long of a given address. I know how to make local api calls but not web ones.

The reason I want to do it this way is because im submitting a form 
   and after the form is submitted, I need to make this GET request to get the lat and long of a given address. I tried doing 2 Ajax calls when I submit the form. One to submit the form to the API then to get the lat/long but I couldnt get it to work together so I want to try to make this call from the controller after the form is sent to the API.

Thanks!

Comment: how have you written your spring mvc, jsp? you should be able to make ajax based api calls in spring mvc as you would do otherwise normally

Comment: @kuhajeyan yeah, let me edit the question so you can understand the problem better.

Comment: @kuhajeyan how do I make calls to a url instead of '/app/create' for example

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a REST client library called RestTemplate: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

There is a guide to using it here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/